# Get live price for token across different Cardano DEXes

Tags: smart-contract, native-assets, oracles, dex

I am working on a small pet project and I need to get the live price data for a token across multiple Cardano DEXes.
For instance, I need the live price of WMT on MinSwap, MuesliSwap, GeniusYield and WingRiders. I am aware DexHunter does something similar as an aggregator, but I cannot figgure out how they do it.

So far my thinking is that:

- I can get this data straight from the DEXes's smart contracts
- I need an oracle for this.

However, I am not sure if these approaches are possible.